# nginx ingress redirect to https based on header

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I have a EKS setup where traffic is sent in the following way.

Users -> Cloudfront -> ALB -> EKS. EKS has an NginX ingress controller.

Currently "force-ssl-redirect" is enabled and hence, NginX ingress controller redirects all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

I want Cloudfront to connect with ALB using HTTP. Hence, I am looking to have a conditional HTTPS redirect in NginX controller.

Hence,

1. I will set a custom header to requests in from Cloudfront
2. If this new header is found, I want NginX controller to return the correct response in HTTP. If not, I want to redirect to HTTPS.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you would like to add a custom header on Cloudfront, and then do a redirect on the Nginx side.

1. You can add custom headers to the request via Cloudfront Functions - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html
2. Then I think you need to use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` annotation in the Ingress Kubernetes resource to add custom configuration to the Nginx location. Maybe something like this can work:

```yaml
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: redirect
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        if ($http_x_custom_header) {
            return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
        }
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NginX configuration map for conditional HTTPS redirection.

You need to create Nginx Configuration with a custom snippet for checking the custom header set by CloudFront.

```
apiVersion: v1
Kind: ConfigMap

Metadata:
Name: nginx-config

Data:

Ssl-redirect-snippet:  |
If ($http_cf_custom_header) {
Return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
Return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

If header is present, NginX returns a 301 redirect with HTTP; if it is not present it will redirect to same URL using HTTPS

Now you need to add configuration map to your NginX ingress controller

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
Kind: Ingress
Metadata:
Name: my-ingress
Annotations:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet:  |
Include /etc/nginx/ssl-redirect-snippet;

Spec:
Rules:
-host: my.domain.com
Http:
Paths:
-Path: /
pathType: Prefix
Backend:
Service:
Name: my-service
Port:
Name: http
```

You need to set CLoudFront to include ‘http_cf_custom_header’ when you are forwarding to ALB. Check this official [page](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/configmap-resource) and for further information check  AWS official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-viewers-to-cloudfront.html).